# K8s Ingress always return 404

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

I am doing practics of K8s ingress but I always got 404 when I hit the address with port. I think my request successfully reached ingress-nginx but ingress did not forward that to service. Please help me. Many thanks

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: mynginx
spec:
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: mynginx
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: mynginx
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: mynginx
          image: nginx
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: mynginx
spec:
  selector:
    app: mynginx
  ports:
  - port: 80
    targetPort: 80
---
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: mynginx
  labels:
    name: mynginx
spec:
  rules:
  - host: "eric.k8s.com"
    http:
      paths:
      - pathType: Prefix
        path: "/"
        backend:
          service:
            name: mynginx
            port: 
              number: 80
```

Comment: what if you remove `pathType: Prefix`？

Comment: can you please share the request you do?

Answer (score 0):

To be able to use `Ingress` you need to deploy an Nginx ingress controller and not just an Nginx pod.

The Nginx ingress controller is more than Nginx, it is a K8s controller that takes care of updating Nginx configuration and loading them with 0-downtime. The source of the Nginx configuration can be either the Nginx config map or the defined ingresses. So each time you create a new Ingress object the controller will make sure that the Nginx configuration has the needed rules to serve the new ingress. Without the controller, you cant use Ingress objects unless you use different tools such as Traefik but in that case, you need a different controller.

you can deploy the controller via helm, as described here

- https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/deploy/
  or vi `kubectl` if you don't use HELM

```
kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/controller-v1.1.1/deploy/static/provider/cloud/deploy.yaml
```

Once you deploy the ingress controller, you can start adding Ingresses

Comment: can you explain a little,  what a `Nginx ingress controller` is, and why it is necessary? is it really a must? from official site: *ingress-nginx is an Ingress controller for Kubernetes using NGINX as a reverse proxy and load balancer.* the OP  just wants to access nginx by ingress, not setting up some controller for k8s, i think?